# Error while using alassestsLibrary

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, alasset

Im trying to use ALAssetsLibrary to load images fromthe photo album
 of iphone/ipad.Im getting the following warning while doing build and archive.

```
ld: warning: in /Users/mark/Projects/Speech_Recognition/Protoype_Test1/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
```

Also i get the error

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-ALAssetsLibrary in PhotoPuller.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is no error while running in simulator , but there im not getting any images returned to me

I have ran out of ideas about what to do

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You haven't linked to the AssetsLibrary framework or your SDK setting isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

please add the these two frame worksin to your project

```
<AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
 <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```